# Unit testing a repository - how to deal with mocking services and dbcontext in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, repository, dbcontext

I'm attempting to unit test a relatively simple repository but I've had difficulty figuring out the best approach for dealing with the services and database contexts that the repository requires to be instantiated.

The repository has one public method, which returns a Member object:

```
public class MemberRepository : IMemberRepository
{
    private OServiceContext _openService;
    private OpenDbContext _openDbContext;

    public MemberRepository(OServiceContext openService, OpenDbContext openDbContext)
    {
        _openService = openService;
        _openDbContext = openDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Member> GetMember(int policyMemberId, int policyActivityId)
    {
        Member member = null;

        var members = await _openDbContext.PolicyMembers
            .Include(c => c.Contact)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PolicyActivityKey == policyActivityId && x.PolicyMemberKey == policyMemberId);

        if (members != null)
        {
            member = ConvertDataToMember(members);
        }

        return member;
    }}
```

The ServiceContext collates four distinct services whose purposes are relatively clear from the CTOR:

```
public OServiceContext(OpenConfiguration config)
    {
        _username = config.Username;
        _password = config.Password;

        _authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(config.GetEndpointConfigurationFor(nameof(AuthenticationService)));
        _dataService = new DataService(config.GetEndpointConfigurationFor(nameof(DataService)));
        _workflowService = new WorkflowService(config.GetEndpointConfigurationFor(nameof(WorkflowService)));
        _documentService = new DocumentService(config.GetEndpointConfigurationFor(nameof(DocumentService)));

        var viewClasses = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof(IOpenHostView).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && x.IsPublic)
            .Select(x => x)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var c in viewClasses)
        {
            var attribute = c.GetCustomAttributesData()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(OpenViewAttribute));

            if (attribute == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException($"Unable to find '{nameof(OpenViewAttribute)}' on {nameof(IOpenView)} implementation $'{c.Name}'.");

            var viewName = attribute.ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();
            var viewConfig = config.GetViewConfigurationFor(viewName);

            if (viewConfig == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException($"Unable to locate key for Open view '{viewName}'.");

            _viewLookup.Add(c, viewConfig.Key);
        }
    }
```

The test as it stands:

```
    [Fact]
    public void MemberRepository_GetMember_ReturnsValidMember()
    {
        //Arrange

        var mockOServiceConfig = new OpenConfiguration()
        {
            Username = "test",
            Password = "pass",
            Remoting = new OpenRemotingConfiguration(),
            Endpoints = new List<OpenHEndpointConfiguration>(){
                new OpenEndpointConfiguration {
                    Reference = "test", ServiceUrl = "test", DatabaseKey = 1, EnableMessageLogging = true
                } },
            Views = new List<OpenViewConfiguration>(),
            Entities = new List<OpenEntityConfiguration>()
        };
        var mockOServiceContext = new Mock<OServiceContext>(mockOServiceConfig);
        var mockOpenDbContext = new Mock<OpenDbContext>();
        var mockOpenDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Member>>();

        mockOpenDbSet.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Member());
        mockOpenDbContext.Setup(s => s.Set<Member>()).Returns(mockOpenDbSet.Object);

        //Act
        var memberRepository = new MemberRepository(mockOServiceContext.Object, mockOpenDbContext.Object);
        var member = memberRepository.GetMember(1, 1);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(member);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Member>(member);
    } 
}
```

This hits an error -

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' config was null.

Basically the params aren't valid for the config when sent to the AuthenticationService. But my question isn't really about fixing the error. Is going down the rabbit hole of trying to pass correct mocked params for all these services really the best approach? Surely there's a better way to mock this when all I want to actually test is a relatively trivial Get method?

Also I'm aware that depending on how you approach the mocked services and data, the unit test can mutate into a integration test. I'd just like to hear the thoughts of anyone who has dealt with something similar. This is honestly the first time I've tried to unit test a repository and while I've tried to consume as much as I can on the topic I would genuinely appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Is OpenDbContext an interface?

Comment: No, it’s the EF context that (for this purpose) contains the Member model. On the backend it calls a SQL view that has all the relevant tables.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with Moq when trying to mock non-interface types. The answer might be creating an intermediary type that defines the properties you need in your application then unit testing that.